# Describing a section of text on a webpage

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to describe some text on a webpage, here is the screenshot(red frame part) and  what I say:
[image]

> On the page, `under` the images album and the three text banners, there should be `a section of texts` and there should be 3 hyper-links in the text section.

I highlighted the parts that I'm not sure whether they are natural or grammatically correct.

Comment: Proofreading is considered as an off-topic question on this site. Nevertheless, the anchor text should be *sign-up* and not *sign-up now*.

Comment: As it stands, I have to agree with Maulik. This looks like simple proofreading, which is indeed off-topic. If you have a specific reason for *why* you think the highlighted parts might be wrong, add that to the question. The reasons and explanation behind it might be on-topic.

Comment: K, I changed the topic, is it a proper topic now?

Comment: @MaulikV Why not sign-up now?

Comment: *Sign up* is not normally hyphenated.  The *now* is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part we can refer to elements on a webpage as we would any type of media. For example, title, heading, subheading, picture, etc. The grammar is unchanged.

For a section of text *text* can be used but so can *paragraph*. *Copy* can be used but it has a narrower definition.